# ImportError: No module named Cloudant

Tags: python, module, cloudant

trying to install cloudant module. Everything I've tried produces `ImportError: No module named Cloudant`  I first tried using `pip install cloud`, my code is Python 2.7 The problems I had are documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272132/cloudant-module-will-not-install-with-pip). The conclusion I took away from that post that there's a bug installing this with python 2.7

Trying to use this module with python 3 I followed the instructions on IBM's page [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-getting-started-python#add_database-python) and used the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/get-started-python
cd get-started-python
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

my code is simply:

```
from cloudant.client import Cloudant
```

My error message is:

```
(env) pi@rpi2:~/hms $ sudo python cloudant-1.1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cloudant-1.1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cloudant.client import Cloudant
ImportError: No module named cloudant.client
```

checking my installation with `pip show cloudant` produces:

```
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/pi/hms/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: requests
Required-by:
Name: cloudant
Version: 2.13.0
Summary: Cloudant / CouchDB Client Library
Home-page: https://github.com/cloudant/python-cloudant
Author: IBM
Author-email: alfinkel@us.ibm.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/pi/hms/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: requests
Required-by:
```

NOTE - For this last attempt I did create a virtual environment, I have not used this before, and I did try w/o the virual environment too.

I've been trying to get this to work for several days.  Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/ , Python 2 is not supported since January 1, 2020.
Can you please try installing python-cloudant on a recent Python 3 version and confirm if the issue still persists?